# Looking for help finding an element in an XML XDocument and updating attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am learning about XML queries and Xdocuments and am having trouble updating an existing element's attributes.  This is my WCF service.  The second part works(creating the new element with attributes.  The problem is that my query must not be returning any results and the code always adds a new element.

```
        //this will insert the officer location and status into the xml data file
    //I read about how to do this at http://prathapk.net/creating-wcf-service-to-store-read-data-in-xml-database/
    //and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx
    public void InsertOfficerData(string OfficerID, double latitude, double longitude, int StatusCode)
    {
        //open xml file
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Officers.xml"));
        //linq query to find the element with the officer ID if it exists
        IEnumerable<XElement> officer =
            from el in doc.Element("Officers").Elements("Officer")
            where (string)el.Attribute("OfficerID") == OfficerID
            select el;

        bool updated = false;
        //update officer attributes
        foreach (XElement el in officer)
        {
            //update attributes
            el.Attribute("Latitude").Value = Convert.ToString(latitude);
            updated = true;
            doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Officers.xml"));
        }
        //if an officer with the id was not found
        if (!updated)
        {
            //add the element with attributes
            doc.Element("Officers").Add(new XElement("Officer",
                new XAttribute("ID", OfficerID),
                new XAttribute("Latitude", latitude),
                new XAttribute("Longitude", longitude),
                new XAttribute("Status", StatusCode)));
            doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Officers.xml"));
        }

    }
```

Sample of my XML file structure:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Officers>
  <Officer ID="Dust" Latitude="4" Longitude="5" Status="3" />
</Officers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking vs an attribute named `OfficerID`, but you are creating only an attribute named `ID`with the new `OfficerID` variable.

Change either

```
where (string)el.Attribute("OfficerID") == OfficerID
```

to be

```
where (string)el.Attribute("ID") == OfficerID
```

OR

change

```
new XAttribute("ID", OfficerID),
```

to be

```
new XAttribute("OfficerID", OfficerID),
```

One other thing that might be critical, is even if you find officers, the search hasn't taken place until you make it. Enumerables delay execution until made to do so. So for your foreach, change it to:

```
foreach (XElement el in officer.ToList())
```

The `ToList()` executes the enumerable, so do others like `ToArray()` etc. Its also a safety net in case you remove elements.

A side note, separate from the question:

Since you call `doc.Save()` in both the foreach and the new officer branch, put the save at the bottom of your method as the last thing that happens.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution given by @Chuck Savage, If each officer has unique ID, You might consider making some changes:
1 you can return single officer. that way you can avoid running foreach code block.
2 Check if the officer exist update it otherwise create. no need to set update true and false.

Comment: Thanks as well.  I was able to get it working as per above but I agree that your suggestion will make this cleaner and will do this as well